# Connect AWS and Azure via OpenVPN

Tags: networking, iptables, vpn, openvpn, azure

I am trying to connect two networks (AWS and Azure) together via OpenVPN. I am aware of other implementations (OpenSwan+Azure GW etc.) but I need maximal portability as I will be expanding this to other cloud vps providers as well.

OpenVPN gateways can ping each other, and each gateway can ping all IPs on the opposing network, but computers on one network cannot ping computers on the other network (neither can they ping the opposing gateways).

What am I missing here? Seems like many are having this issue for various reasons, but after 50+ tries I gave up and decided to ask :)

**Network 1:**

dev tun
port 1194
ifconfig 10.8.223.40 10.8.223.41
route 10.22.1.0 255.255.255.0 vpn_gateway
comp-lzo
keepalive 10 60
persist-key
persist-tun
user nobody
group nobody
secret /etc/openvpn/static.key

```
ip route
default via 10.0.1.1 dev eth0
10.0.1.0/27 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.1.9
10.22.1.0/24 via 10.8.223.41 dev tun0
10.33.0.0/24 via 10.33.0.2 dev tun2
10.33.0.2 dev tun2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.33.0.1
10.8.223.41 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.223.40
```

**Network 2**

dev tun
port 1194
remote my_ext_ip 1194
ifconfig 10.8.223.41 10.8.223.40
route 10.0.0.0 255.254.0.0 vpn_gateway
comp-lzo
keepalive 10 60
persist-key
persist-tun
user nobody
group nobody
secret /etc/openvpn/static.key

```
ip route
default via 10.22.1.1 dev eth0
10.0.0.0/15 via 10.8.223.40 dev tun0
10.22.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.22.1.9
10.8.223.40 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.223.41
```

**Here's what I have iptables-wise:**

**Both networks:** iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

**Network 1:** iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s "10.0.0.0/15" -o "eth0" -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 10.0.0.0/15 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s "10.8.223.40/32" -o "eth0" -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 10.8.223.40/32 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT

**Network 2:** iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s "10.22.1.0/24" -o "eth0" -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 10.22.1.0/24 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s "10.8.223.41/32" -o "eth0" -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 10.8.223.41/32 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT

My assumption was (since I have separate gateways for internet access) that I now have to add routes to each non-gateway computer on both networks that will route packets destined for the opposite network via the local OpenVPN gateway.

I did that for machine 10.0.1.7:

**ip route add 10.22.1.0/24 via 10.0.1.9**

So now I have:

> default via 10.0.1.1 dev eth0
> 10.0.1.0/27 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.1.7
> 10.22.1.0/24 via 10.0.1.9 dev eth0
> 172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.42.1

but traceroute to 10.22.1.9 (opposing gateway) still doesn't go anywhere...

P.S. Most of my machines are in Docker, but I get the same results from the host machine as well.

Any help would be highly appreciated!